# GET /signup - - ms - -(both get and post not working, it was a while idk whats wrong)

Tags: node.js, backend

1.GET /signup - - ms - -(both GET and POST not working, it was a while I don’t know whats wrong)
2. please check below code
3.server.js. This this the app code that you have requested.Kindly go through it. Also the value for link is replaced by word link as it is private.
4. There are two files in this. Server.js and user.js kindly check it out.

```
var router = require("express").Router();
var User = require("../models/user.js");
router.get("/signup", function(req, res){
    res.send("hello");
});

router.post('/signup', function(req, res, next){
    var user = new User();
    user.profile.name = req.body.name;
    user.email = req.body.email;
    user.password = req.body.password;
    User.findOne( { email : req.body.email }, function(err, existingUser) {
        if(existingUser){
            console.log(req.body.email + "already exists");
            return res.redirect("/signup");
        }
        else{
            user.save(function(err, user){
                if(err) return next(err);
                res.send("New user has been added");
            });
        }
    });
});

module.exports = router;




//server.js code
var express    = require("express");
var morgan     = require("morgan");
var mongoose   = require("mongoose");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var User       = require("./models/user.js");
var ejs        = require("ejs");
var engine     = require("ejs-mate");


var app = express();
mongoose.connect('link', function(err){
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
    }
    else{
        console.log("connected to database");
    }
});

//middle ware
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use(morgan('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
app.engine("ejs", engine);
app.set("view engine", "ejs");

var mainRoutes = require("./routes/main.js");
var userRoutes = require("./routes/user.js");
app.use(mainRoutes,function(err){
    if(err){
        console.log("error is here")
    }
});
app.use(userRoutes, function(err){
    if(err){
        console.log("error is here in 2" );
    }
});

//listen to port 3000 
app.listen(3000, function(err){
    if(err) throw err;
    console.log("Server has started");
});
```

Comment: Please share your app code if you have any, if you don't - that's why nothing is working :)

Comment: I've added the app code.Please check it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

removed the call back function from app.use() and it worked.